# Din of Lachem by arba minim when saying Hallel

Tags: halacha, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hallel

On the first day of sukkos there is a din of "lachem" by the arba minim that they must belong to you in order to fulfill the mitzvah. After someone has already made a bracha on his arba minim and fulfilled the mitzvah when the person then takes the arba minim again to shake them by Hallel must they also still "belong" to him with all of the dininm of "lachem". Or may he use someone else's (without making some sort of kinyan (acquisition) on them.)

Comment: Extra Na'anuim (such as what we do in Hallel) should probably be with all Dinim (would you use them for Halel if you has only 1 Hadas?), including "Lochem".

Comment: @JNF I think you have it backwards. The Hallel Na'anuim are the main ones. Any done after the original bracha are the extra ones.

Comment: @DoubleAA, nonetheless, one is _yotze_ the first time he holds the _minim_ together.

Comment: @msh210 One is yotze the mitzva of holding. One is not yotze the mitzva of waving in hallel.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the Na'anuim are _Shiurei Mitzvah_, when we say the bracha it's for being Yotzeh.

Comment: @JNF Please source that in the Gemara if you say it's for being Yotzei. The Mishna ([Sukka 3:9](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%92_%D7%98)) is clear that the Naanuim are done in Hallel and that's what eveyone seems to be talking about when saying Shiyarei Mitzva. Where do you see Naanuim not in Hallel?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think we're missing eachother. What I was saying that one is Yotzeh by holding them together (like msh210 wrote). Na'anuim should probably be done with a Kosher set (i.e. one that you _would_ be Yotzeh with)

Comment: This happened to someone in my shul this year. He left his house in the morning (having already shaken arba minim before davening) and by mistake took his father's arba minim which he used by Hallel.

Comment: @JNF Na'anuim done hours after being yotzei are probably pointless whether it's a kosher set or not. If you choose to do the mitzva by picking up the lulav not during the ideal time of hallel, that is your choice, and you miss out on doing the mitzva in the ideal way. You can't go back and do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nitei Gavriel Hilchos Arbas HaMinim Perek 44 Sif 3 (with note 3) he brings down there that during Hallel and Hoshanos one is yotzee if they use a borrowed lulav (or similar -- i.e. the dinim of "lechem" do not apply.) In the footnote there he brings this from the Mikorei Kodoesh (Page 78) that since the ninuim of Hallel even on the first day are only m'drabbanan (the person was yotzee the mitzvah of netilas lulav d'oraisa when he took the arba minim with a bracha before Hallel) therefore one doesn't to be makpid on dinim of "lechem" (as well as chasar) since it's like the other days of sukkos that the mitzvah of netilas lulav is only m'drabbanan and doesn't require all the same dinim of the first that is m'doraisa.

See here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46438&st=&pgnum=182&hilite=